# d3.js CSV element in-line

Tags: csv, d3.js

Folks-

I'm making a viz based on Mike Bostock's http://bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/.

As this will be mailed and viewed locally rather than staged on a server it's necessary to embed the JS library, and any data in the document.

I have successfully integrated the javascript, as well as a JSON object. I'm having difficulty getting the CSV file included and then iterating over it.

```
var myMatrix = '[[0,557.3,0,0,0,1645.8,0,903.2,895.6,615.7,0,408.1,0,845.3,290.1,325,73.5],[788.1,0,0,0,1204.2,1859.7,1020.5,1160,976.4,1057,1082.4,0,697.2,0,614.2,0,0]]';

svg.append("circle")
.attr("r", outerRadius);

d3.csv("companies.csv", function(companies) {
  //d3.json("matrix.json", function(matrix) {

matrix = JSON.parse(myMatrix); //new


// Compute the chord layout.
layout.matrix(matrix);
    ...<snip>
```

So basically I need to replace the "d3.csv" function with something that will operate on an in-line data set while still iterating over the rest of the function.

Thanks,

RL

Comment: Your best bet is to convert the CSV to JSON and inclue it in the Javascript file like you did for `matrix`.

Comment: the companies.csv conversion is a function that iterates over all the subsequent data transformations, while the technique I used with "matrix = JSON.parse(myMatrix)" does all the work on one line. How would I rewrite the 'companies.csv' transformation that it iterates over all the subsequent transformations?

Comment: You could simply save the result of your CSV conversion.

Comment: I need to EMBED the csv data, instead of linking to an external file. Then I need to replace the function: "d3.json("companies.csv", function(companies) { ... 
I'm not clear on how to do that.

Comment: In your initial version, you end up with a variable after conversion. You could save that variable as JSON and then embed it into the code.

Answer (score 1):

Lars- you're right. I was overthinking it.

I just added the JSON object in and the d3 magically iterated over the items in the object.

```
var companies = [{name:"one", color:"#8a8a8a"},{name:"two", color:"#5d9a0c"},{name:"three", color:"#005a8b"}}];
```

thanks,

RL